# Is it possible to put an element on top of another without blocking the back element's links?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, I can think of a solution where I reduce the width of the top element to avoid covering up the link, but I want to see if this is possible without doing so.

The problem: Put a navigation bar over the top part of a Google Maps map without blocking the 'Map' and 'Satellite' links.

[image: figure1]

EDIT: Example here
http://www.lobagola.com/contacts.html

I wonder how they achieved it, you can still click the Map and Satellite links even with an element on top of it.

Comment: @ruakh 
Sorry if it was a bit confusing!

Basically, I have a page set up that contains a full width Google Maps, along with a Top Navigation Menu (the darkened part of the image I posted).

Sadly, after setting up the page, I failed to realize that the Map | Satellite links from google maps are blocked by the menu.

Comment: In my opinion, there are only two ways: either you redo the buttons on top, linking their click to the click on the buttons below (quite awful, IMHO) or lift the z-axis of the buttons and put your stuff in between. Both are non-optimal solutions but the second one is a lot better. I cannot think of another way to do it.

Comment: If I understand correct, you want to hide Google Maps API controls? Do you wanna hide zoom and move buttons to? - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI

Comment: No, not hide it.

I want to put something transparent on top of it, without covering the API controls.

Answer (score 5):

Consider CSS `pointer-events: none`

> `none`
> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

```js
function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 #map-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
      }
#nav{
  color: #FFF;
  pointer-events: none; /* disabled mouse interaction */
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left:12px;
  }

#nav ul li{
  display:inline;
  margin-left:10px;
  }
#nav ul a{
  text-decoration:none;
   pointer-events: auto; /* re-enable mouse interaction for links */
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The effect is possible applying the CSS property `pointer-events: none` to the bar over the map, which allows the mouse events to go through it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score -1):

The link would be a `position:relative` with a `z-index` while the page header has a transparent background with `position:absolute` on top of that map/background, thus making the link clickable.

The position: absolute takes the page header out of the flow and positions it on top of the screen, while the z-index on the link makes it visible to the user to interact.

```
.link {
  float: right;
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}

.page-header {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can see a working example here[1], contrast that with a page header with a white background here[2]

[1] http://jsbin.com/nawuva/1/edit

[2] http://jsbin.com/nawuva/2/edit

Comment: My bad, didn't foresee that the google map is sitting inside an iframe. `pointer-events: none` is the right solution.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to thanix.  However I would wait for load complete and then bump the z-index

```
$('.gmnoprint').css({z-index : 10});
```